# HTML input type time problem with Chrome when typing

Tags: angularjs, html, google-chrome

I hope I find solution for this.
I have the following html tag for an angularjs project that should help select time.

```
<input class="input-time" type='time' ng-model="dr.startTime">
```

The time is shown in AM/PM format which I am okay with. The problem is I try to type in the hour: **12** but if you are not fast enough (like instant clicking 1+2) it only changes the second digit of the time. Some times even when I do it super fast, it shows the second digit.
Kindly help to work around this.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I guess is Chrome. which version? I have tried in Chrome (v73) and is working fine. The only case where it happens is if you click the arrow button and then you type a number. In that case, as there is already a number, you're typing only the second one so after typing it the cursos jumps to the minutes field

Comment: I am using chrome Version 72.0.3626.119 on Ubuntu 18.
When you type 12 does it work fine?

Comment: Yes it does in 72.0.3626.121

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it doesn't exist any know issue with `time input` in lasts versions of Chrome:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

You can test in the following code snnipet. It's working fine for me.

```html
<input class="input-time" type='time' ng-model="dr.startTime">
```

The only case where it happens is if you click the arrow button and then you type a number. In that case, as there is already a number, you're typing only the second one so after typing it the cursor jumps to the minutes field.